# IntelliJ is not recognizing annotation-generated class files

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, annotations, annotation-processing

I have a custom annotation in Java, that uses [ByteBuddy](https://bytebuddy.net) to generate a new class based on the annotated one. Since ByteBuddy is already compiling the class, I am outputting the bytecode directly, rather than source.

My gradle build compiles fine, with references to the generated class.

The problem is that in IntelliJ, the editor does not recognize the classes that are output directly. It *does* recognize classes generated as source.

##### My Annotation sub-project

gradle.build

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group 'org.example'
version 'unspecified'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.12.23'
}
```

MyAnnotation.java

```
package org.example.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

MyAnnotationProcessor.java

```
package org.example.annotation.processor;

import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;

import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"org.example.annotation.MyAnnotation"})
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_11)
public class MyAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    Filer filer;

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
        filer = processingEnv.getFiler();
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        annotations.forEach(a -> {
            try {
                // Generate a java source file
                var className = a.getSimpleName()+"_source";
                var sourceFile = filer.createSourceFile(className);
                var sourceFileWriter = sourceFile.openWriter();
                sourceFileWriter.write("package org.example.annotation; public class "+className+" {}");
                sourceFileWriter.close();

                // Generate a java class file
                var otherClassName = a.getSimpleName()+"_bytecode";
                var bb = new ByteBuddy();
                var otherClass = bb.subclass(Object.class)
                      .name(otherClassName)
                      .make();
                var otherClassFile = filer.createClassFile(otherClassName);
                var otherClassFileOS = javaFileObject.openOutputStream();
                otherClassFileOS.write(otherClass.getBytes());
                otherClassFileOS.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Notice that I am outputting one class called `MyAnnotation_source` and one called `MyAnnotation_bytecode`

##### My sub-project that uses the annotation

gradle.build  (**NOTE** that `core` is the name of the annotation sub-project)

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version 'unspecified'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
    annotationProcessor project(':core')
}
```

UserTest.java

```
import org.example.annotation.MyAnnotation;
import org.example.annotation.MyAnnotation_source;
import org.example.annotation.MyAnnotation_bytecode; //Cannot resolve symbol 'MyAnnotation_bytecode'
 
@MyAnnotation
public class UserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyAnnotation_source foo = new MyAnnotation_source();
        MyAnnotation_bytecode other = new MyAnnotation_bytecode(); //Cannot resolve symbol 'MyAnnotation_bytecode'
    }
}
```

The build directory ends up looking like this:

```
build/
├─ classes
│  └─ java
│     └─ main
│        ├─ MyAnnotation_bytecode.class         <-- Generated
│        ├── UserTest.class
│        └── org
│            └─ example
│               └─ annotation
│                  └─ MyAnnotation_source.class <-- Compiled
└─ generated
   └─ sources
      └─ annotationProcessor
         └─ java
            └─ main
               └─ MyAnnotation_source.java      <-- Generated
```

I have already tried various configurations of the annotation processor settings in IntelliJ, but I think the answer is somewhere else.

### Update

I logged this bug with IntelliJ [IDEA-314406](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-314406) but the ticket was closed without addressing it at all. There was just a highly unsatisfactory (and condescending) comment on it.

Comment: If you have the `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Annotation Processors` enabled but it still doesn't help. This might be an issue in the IDEA and you could report a bug report at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: @LJreplica, I have indeed enabled the annotation processors there, and tried a few variants of the configuration.